# Unable to install AMDOverclockCNTRL

Tags: drivers, 18.04, software-installation, amd-graphics, fancontrol

I've recently migrated to Ubuntu(18.04.2 LTS) 64bit from Windows as Windows had been quiet bloated lately. I've wanted to control the speed of my GPU(ATI Radeon HD5970 2Gb) Fan as it gets warm quite fast under load and I want to manually set a high constant speed on it. I've tried using the sensors command on terminal but it does not show the RPM nor lets me change it, and I've also heard that there is an utility called AMDOverdriveCNTRL, which I've downloaded the deb file from Sourceforge but when I install it using package installer it appears as if it installs (shows percentage and then says 100%), but then after completion it shows up as install once more. Please assist me with this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMDOverdriveCNTRL has not been updated in years.  You could try to ask questions on their sourceforge page.  The installer requires wxWidgets 2.8, but 3.0 is installed and it does not like that.  You could download the source code and attempt to compile it, but I wasn't having much luck with that either.